# ExtJS 4 desktop module windows stretch destop/taskbar when opened with sizes/positions that make them exceed desktop size

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

If I call `createWindow` on a module and give it `width,` `height`, `x` and `y` values, the window will open fine, but makes the desktop and/or taskbar look stretched.

For example, if there's a window being opened whose bottom border is below the taskbar, not only will it cover the taskbar, it will continue shifting the whole destop down, making the top disappear, and the taskbar will stretch all the way to the bottom of the form.

Ideally, I would like to have the overlapping part of the window slide off the screen and under the taskbar.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.locations.Module', {

.......

createWindow:        function (width, height, x, y) {

    this.width  = width  || 740;
    this.height = height || 480;

    var b = this.app.getDesktop();
    var a = b.getWindow('locations-module-window');

    if (!a) {

        this.locationsGrid   = Ext.create('MyApp.view.locations.Grid');
        this.locationsFilter = Ext.create('MyApp.view.locations.Filter');

        this.locationsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            bodyPadding:       0,
            border:            true,
            fieldDefaults:     {
                labelAlign:   'left',
                msgTarget:    'side'
            },
            frame:             false,
            header:            false,
            id:               'locations-module-panel',
            layout:           'border',
            defaults:          {
                bodyStyle:    'padding: 15px',
                collapsible:   true,
                split:         true
            },
            items:             [
                this.locationsGrid,
                this.locationsFilter
            ]
        });

        a = b.createWindow({

            animCollapse:      true,
            border:            false,
            collapsible:       true,
            constrainHeader:   false,
            height:            this.height,
            width:             this.width,
            x:                 x,
            y:                 y,
            iconCls:          'icon-locations',
            id:               'locations-module-window',
            layout:           'fit',
            maximizable:       true,
            minimizable:       true,
            title:            'Locations',
            items:             [{
                activeTab:     0,
                defaults:      {
                    border:    false,
                    header:    false
                },
                xtype:        'tabpanel',
                items:         [{
                    iconCls:  'icon-locations',
                    layout:   'fit',
                    title:    'Branches',
                    items:     this.locationsPanel
                },{
                    html:     "<p>Region items go here.</p>",
                    iconCls:  'icon-regions',
                    title:    "Regions"
                }]
            }]
        });
    };

    a.show();
    return a
},

....
```

Answer (score 0):

See this comment from `Ext.window.Window`'s [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.window.Window):

> By default, Windows will be rendered to document.body. To constrain a Window to another element specify renderTo.

So, set `renderTo` to whatever panel is meant to contain all of the windows.  Presumably that panel doesn't overlap the "taskbar" so then the window won't either.